# Express Form: Get submitted data on success page

Tags: craft3, plugin-expressforms

I have a very simple question.

In Craft CMS, using Express Forms (free edition), I have a classic scenario.

1. Page with the form, created by the form.openTag() method
2. A success page which has '/success' url, and an associated success.twig template file

In the success page, I would like to say something like:
"Thank you `{{ surname }}`!"

Where `{{ surname }}` is the surname that user has inserted in the form page, on the input with `name="surname"`.

Is this possible?